# Where is the correct occurence of the world "also" in sentences?

Tags: word-choice, word-order, adverb-placement, too-also

I noticed that I use this word much. The problem is that I don't know where should I put it in the sentence! Sometimes I say for example:

> I like T.V and **also** radio.

Is the sentence above OK?

- How must I use "also" correctly in sentences?
- And what is the difference between "also" and "too"?
- When to use one but not the other?

Answer (score 2):

@kcdude That's a good page, but it doesn't tell you much about the idiomatic use of the word, which I think is the crux of the issue.

"And also" is grammatically correct, but not idiomatically; if you're not familiar with the word "idiom" or "idiomatically," well, it's kind of vague, but it basically means "in common use." If you say something that is grammatically correct but "sounds wrong," it's probably not idiomatically correct.

"I like TV and radio" or "I like both TV and radio" would be the typical way to phrase that sentence. "Also" can imply that you forgot something ("I need to take out the trash first. Also, I need to do the laundry."), like a verbal version of a P.S. (post-script) in a letter. It can imply that something is attributed to something else unexpectedly ("This blender also acts as an egg-beater!"). These are typical uses of the word "also" in colloquial English. "And also" is redundant, because both "and" and "also" mean the same thing in this context. You could say "I like TV, also radio" if you wanted, although I'm not sure if that's grammatically correct.

Comment: So, Using "also" is limited to the cases when you want to add a piece of unexpected information or when we add something which we previously forgot, right? No other uses?

Comment: Well, it's not strictly that. I'm not an expert on idiom (grammar is more my forte) so I can't lay it out cut-and-dried for you. Those two cases are, from my experience, the most common uses of "also." Usually, though, from what I've seen and heard, using it any other way makes it sound awkward.

As a side note, I don't think "I like TV, also radio" is grammatically correct, since it is a comma splice (without the comma, it's a sentence plus a fragment). However, in colloquial English, nobody would bat an eye at you saying that.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to say - I like TV and radio too. You might want to view this page
http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/also.html

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please add some explanation for your answer. Also, links to external sites are insufficient for an answer. Please include a summary or a relevant excerpt too.